# D-Bus API for cron

Tags: c++, c, linux, cron, dbus

Is there D-Bus API (e.g. CAPI) for `cron`?

It would be very handy to be able to add a jobs programmatically.

Current solution is to create crontab-file then run `crontab crontab-file` as a child process. It is not very elegant solution, due to extra operations: creation of file and running of the child process.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with C++, but I think systemd's DBus API lets you programmatically control Timer units. Maybe worth looking at if you don't mind being limited to systemd distros?

Comment: I'm not aware of any API; however you're asking this in the wrong direction - any dbus integration would need to be implemented in the `cron` service itself. Opinion: cron management is generally seen as a systems administration task, and not a programmer task; which is why you generally don't see programmer APIs for them.

Comment: @Petesh NetworkManager, ModemManager, AccountService also looks like a system administration tasks, but they are accessible though D-Bus API. I need a way to power off and power on on week days differently. Using `rtcwake` and `shutdown -P`.

Comment: My last sentence was a bit throwaway, but the main gist of my point was that you need to find an implementation of cron that can talk dbus, and make it a dependency of your program. There are multiple cron implementations; none of which I'm aware of that have dbus hooks.